# I want to kill off my splash screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, plymouth

Previous title:  Lubuntu splash screen problem bc of Nvidia driver.

I'm new to linux and getting under the hood of computers in general.  I'm doing my research but it'll take awhile for me to gain a working literacy in this respect. Please bear with me if I use incorrect terminology.  I'll try to explain what I mean clearly enough for you to infer. Ubuntu saved my hide when Windows XP crashed on me and now I'm using Lubuntu. I love the idea of open source and not being at the mercy of Windows. I use Timeshift to go about things empirically (ie undoing everything I did so I don't get in over my head and cause new problems).

With that out of the way, here's the problem:  My splash screen at boot up and shut down is broken and I'm unable to fix it. It annoys me to no end, and I'm not sure if this is indicative of other problems with my graphics card's performance. I don't know what optimal performance looks like with the card because I just got it. I'm tired of plugging in various commands into the terminal, plymouth-related or otherwise, and getting nowhere. Most of the time I get info that solves my problems but not with this.

When I use any of the Nvidia graphics card's proprietary drivers, the splash screen turns into a blue screen with a janky font that looks like it's straight out of the 80s. The logo and the dots look nasty when this happens. It doesn't freeze up or anything.  When I go back to the open source driver, I get the nice logo back.  My understanding is that I need to use the proprietary driver for 3D graphics, so I'd like to just cut the splash screen out of the bootup/shutdown process entirely.  I'd rather see a black screen for a few more seconds if I can't fix it.

How do I go about that? Is it possible?

Sorry if this has been addressed in another thread.  I'm not sure if 'disabling the splash screen' is the search that puts me on the right track.

Thanks in advance for any polite responses.

Comment: Mikewhatever:  Thanks for reading. Pretty sure I've tried all of the possible solutions except one to no avail.  I'll try it, but I'm not optimistic. (I'm regretting buying that card.) I'm more interested in finding a way to just skip the splash screen entirely and see a black screen for a few more seconds.  Maybe that's easier than banging my head against the wall trying to fix it.

Comment: You can try to follow this: http://askubuntu.com/a/19487/16395, just instead of adding a parameter substitute the `quiet splash` with `nosplash`. Should get rid of the boot splash screen for good.

Comment: I tried both solutions on that page. I didn't get the file with the bold type.  I'm having trouble with the file editing on the terminal.  When I plug in commands such as gedit, gksudo, nano, (I think those are the one but not sure since I'm at work), I get blank files even when I put sudo in front of anything. I tried both solutions on that page. I didn't get the file with the bold type.  I'm having trouble with the file editing on the terminal.  When I plug in commands such as gedit, gksudo, and nano, I get blank files even when I put sudo in front of anything.

Comment: Anyway, I tried solution two after editing a file from the grub from quiet to nosplash and had to restore with timeshift bc I couldn't undo it.  Then solution 2 with Grub Customizer. Still reams of text before bootup but no splash screen.  After I undid my changes to that one, I rebooted and whaddaya know. It worked somehow.

Comment: So to summarize:  Tried #1. Nope. Undo unsuccessful. Tried #1+#2 for the heck of it. Nope. Restored to undo changes.  Tried #2 by itself. Nope. Undid changes to #2 supposedly, and got the result that I wanted for some reason. I don't get computers.